# Get device/model information from Android via Python

Tags: android, python

Good day all!

Hoping one of you Gurus can help me out with this issue.

I am currently writing an app in Python which pulls device manuals from their websites and creates a User Manual shortcut for it to be launched.

So far so good, but in the long run I would like to set it up to pull the manufacturer/model number from the Android OS and search according to the specific model.

The problem? I can't for the life of me find anything Pythonic that can pull such information from the system? From searching Google, I was able to find out that in native languages, they can access android.os.Build to obtain such information but I cannot figure out how to access this via Python?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: No answer but I like your idea.

Comment: Thanks, as a senior support specialist for a mobile device manufacturer, I have a good idea how much people NEED THEIR MANUALS! As most manufacturers are starting to opt out of hard copies, the older generations that are not so technically inclined are left without a way to learn their device and trying to guide them to a site, install Adobe Ready, etc. is not as easy of a task as you would like to believe! ;)

Comment: Is it an Android app (written in Python) or a Desktop app?

Comment: Android app, written in Python using SL4A (scripting layer)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If this is not yet available via SL4A Facade API, you can use shell command `getprop` retrieve device/model information which are actually stored in file `/system/build.prop`, your are interested on **ro.product.manufacturer** and **ro.product.model** properties:

```
[ro.product.manufacturer]: [samsung]
[ro.product.model]: [GT-I9100]
```

For how to run shell command from Python, check out this Q&A:

[Running shell command from python and capturing the output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760215/running-shell-command-from-python-and-capturing-the-output)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks!! That works just as good, my main concern is to obtain the information, I do not mind using a shell command to obtain it until they have a more native method available. Did a little test run and it worked out perfectly!

Comment: P.S. wont let me award the bounty for 2 hours. Check back a bit later and it should be received. Thanks again!